# Combining 2 BeautifulSoup Queries into 1 csv Row

Tags: python, csv

Basically I am trying to take 2 different BeautifulSoup Queries and display them on the same CSV line.
I am new to python so if you have an other suggestions for my code please let me know.

I am able to select the correct data with both functions however I can not figure out how to combine them.

If it were not for the 4 empty rows that show up for print_list() function, both the print_list() function and the get_links() function would have the same number of rows.

What I want is a table listed as follows:
    4 columns from print_list() then 1 column from get_links()

Any help would be awesome!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import csv

links_list = []

url = 'http://www.sedar.com/DisplayCompanyDocuments.do?lang=EN&issuerNo=00010447'
sedar = urllib2.urlopen(url)
read_sedar = sedar.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(read_sedar)

def print_list():
    with open('sedar.csv', 'wb') as outputfile:
        writer = csv.writer(outputfile)
        tds = soup.find_all('td')
        for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
            tds = tr.find_all('td')
            row = [elem.text.encode('utf-8') for elem in tds[0:len(tds)-1]]
            writer.writerow(row)

def get_links():
    for form in soup.find_all('form'):
        links_list.append(form.get('action'))
    return links_list
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to combine the corresponding elements from both the lists returned by the functions.

```
def print_list():
    tds = soup.find_all('td')
    for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
        tds = tr.find_all('td')
        row = [elem.text.encode('utf-8') for elem in tds[0:len(tds)-1]]
    return row

def get_links():
    for form in soup.find_all('form'):
        links_list.append(form.get('action'))
    return links_list

def write_to_output():
    first_four_cols = print_list()
    last_col = links_list()
    with open('sedar.csv', 'wb') as outputfile:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(outputfile)
        for row in zip(first_four_cols, last_col):
            csv_writer.write(row)
```

To explain how `zip()` works, consider two lists:

```
>>> a_list = ['one', 'two', 'three']
>>> b_list = ['four', 'five', 'six']
>>> for item in zip(a_list, b_list):
...     print item
...
('one', 'four')
('two', 'five')
('three', 'six')
```

Comment: thanks man, for the write_to_output() part for last_col it should be get_links() not links_list().  However it still outputs nothing...  I have a feeling it has to do with the "row" part just before I "return row"